# A word/phrase which refers to the smell of nature?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Similar to the word 'petrichor' in its purpose. I'm looking for a word/phrase that can be used to describe the smell of grass/pollen/trees/wood/earth essentially the outdoors.

Similar to the smell of a garden or wooded area in the summer or perhaps freshly mowed grass?

Comment: _fragrance_ is generally used for prevailing smell in flower gardens.

Comment: *Before the winter ploughing, Beauce is covered in manure as far as the eye can see. Under the pale September skies, from dawn till dusk, carts brimming with steaming piles of old litter would make their way slowly along country roads as though delivering heat itself to the land...a sort of heaving, surging, sea of manure from cowshed and stable...the whole future growth of spring was borne along on this fermenting flood of [decomposition]... And from one end of the vast plain to the other, you could smell the stench of all this animal excrement, from which man's daily bread would come*.

Comment: The above is taken from the novel *La Terre* by Emile Zola (translated by Douglas Parmée), and is one of my favourite passages about the countryside. It doesn't supply you with a word but I think it says that *fragrance* may not be the one you are seeking as @JonyAgarwal suggests.

Comment: Aw, what's wrong with the (coined) word _petrichoric_?

Comment: @WS2 But I used it for flower GARDENS. That passage refers to a countryside farm.

Comment: @El What's wrong with *petrichoric*? Answer - most of my interlocutors wouldn't have the faintest idea what it meant! I'll try it out on my wife next time we are out in the country!

Comment: Petrichor is normally used when referring to the smell of earth and nature after a downpour :). @Exal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not specifically olfactory, but I'd use [**Bucolic**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bucolic):

> of or characteristic of the countryside or country life; rustic (-- Collins)

from [*The Daily Telegraph* wine review](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/wine/10863147/Jura-wine-the-grapes-that-took-Manhattan.html), May 2014:

> But I also remember the imprint of bewilderment: what is this extraordinary wine with such a distinctively pale garnet colour; that comes at you with the spooling fluidity of pinot noir, but which, in place of pinot’s fragrant nosegay of berries and cherry blossom, has a calmer, bucolic smell, very outdoorsy?

Comment: I like this one. Upvote.

Comment: Ooo this is very nice!

Answer (score 5):

The "outdoors" smells like a lot of things! I can think of a words referring to various specific scents that recall being out in nature:

earthy, woodsy / woody, mossy, mildewed, moldy, pine, loamy, flowery, fresh. And more of a stretch: crisp, musky, animalic, sweet, heady (like 'the thick smell of nectar')

I mean, there is that *something* where you breathe "some fresh air" and just feel *good*, and I find the most evocative descriptions of it have to be phrases, usually by a damn good writer. For your perusal, here is [an article devoted to petrichor perfumes](https://intothegloss.com/2015/03/petrichor-perfume-rain-scent/) with a couple cool descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

*Woodsy fragrance* is broadly used to refer to the smell of forest.

[Woodsy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woodsy) is defined in Merriam-Wesber:

> relating to or suggesting the forest

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest [**pastoral fragrance**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pastoral+fragrance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpastoral%20fragrance%3B%2Cc0).

Pastoral:

1. having the simplicity, charm, serenity, or other characteristics generally attributed to rural areas.
2. pertaining to the country or life in the country; rural, rustic.

([Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pastoral))